# Weight paint brush behaving weirdly

Tags: weight-painting, brushes

The brush in weight painting mode is acting really strangely for me. It barely seems to go over the parts that I'm trying to paint, or like it can only hit very specific spots. It's making it very difficult to work.

Here's a gif of how my brush works
[image]

If anyone could help me figure this out and what I could do to fix it, I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what's the problem here, your object is very low-poly, weight painting will assign a weight to a vertex, and visually it will create a gradient between the painted vertex and the adjacent, that's what is happening right here, please tell what is the problem in more details and what you're expecting?

Comment: As @moonboots says, this looks totally normal. Weight painting is not like texture painting. The weights are stored in the vertices - so very large faces with just a few vertices on the edges cannot be painted directly in the middle of the faces. For that you need vertices inbetween. Have you done tutorials on weight painting to learn how it works?